# Unit Test empty Task with Moq

Tags: c#, .net, moq, .net-6.0

I have the following method

```
Task SendMessage(ServiceBusRequest serviceBusRequest);
```

And in my unit test I am doing this

```
 _serviceBusAdapter.Setup(p => p.SendMessage(It.IsAny<ServiceBusRequest>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(default(object)));
```

However, this is throwing a null reference exception.  What am I doing wrong here?

I also tried doing

```
_serviceBusAdapter.Setup(p => p.SendMessage(It.IsAny<ServiceBusRequest>())).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```

but it is also throwing the same exception

I am using the following package

```
<PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.16.0" />
```

Comment: *this is throwing a null reference exception*. What do you mean by *this*? The call to `Setup`, or an exception within your SUT? If the latter, show the actual code under test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning `Task.CompletedTask`. [Link to documenation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_CompletedTask)

Comment: I tried that as well
 _serviceBusAdapter.Setup(p => p.SendMessage(It.IsAny<ServiceBusRequest>())).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);  but still giving me null reference exception

Comment: Check the exception details, stacktrace, etc.. Where exactly does the null reference happen? What reference is null and where? The code looks fine, so there must be an issue somewhere else that you didn't show us. Is `_serviceBusAdapter` null?

Comment: I am initializing it here:::

private readonly Mock<IServiceBusAdapter> _serviceBusAdapter = new Mock<IServiceBusAdapter>();

Comment: The service bus object was passed as null in the constructor.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an issue with the parameter itself. Have you tried this ?

```
var mockRequest = new Mock<ServiceBusRequest>();
_serviceBusAdapter.Setup(p => p.SendMessage(mockRequest.Object)).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```

Comment: Tried that as well but still getting
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @MAK Are you sure your method is not throwing any exception ?

Comment: I debugged the method and when it reaches here:
 // Send message to service bus queue
                        await _serviceBusAdapter.SendMessage(serviceBusRequest);

I get the error

Comment: Provide more code about that method please. It's not quite clear tbh.